# Slixmpp - Bot can´t connect to multiuser room

Tags: python, xmpp

I´m trying to connect my slixmpp bot to Cisco Jabber as documented in their [examples](https://slixmpp.readthedocs.io/en/slix-1.7.0/getting_started/muc.html). I have created a new Jabber user for my bot and I am able to talk to it directly. So the configs on the jabber server should be okay. After running the script I am waiting in the MUC room for the bot to join but he won´t.

Unfortunately I can´t find any further information in the docs. Someone here who worked with slixmpp in MUC rooms in the past and knows where the error occures?

Here is my code:

```
import slixmpp
import logging
from argparse import ArgumentParser

class MUCBot(slixmpp.ClientXMPP):

    def __init__(self, jid, password, room, nick):
        slixmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password)

        self.room = room
        self.nick = nick

        self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.start)

    async def start(self, event):
        await self.get_roster()
        self.send_presence()
        self.plugin['xep_0045'].join_muc(self.room, self.nick)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setup the command line arguments.
    parser = ArgumentParser()

    # Output verbosity options.
    parser.add_argument("-q", "--quiet", help="set logging to ERROR",
                        action="store_const", dest="loglevel",
                        const=logging.ERROR, default=logging.INFO)
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", help="set logging to DEBUG",
                        action="store_const", dest="loglevel",
                        const=logging.DEBUG, default=logging.INFO)

    # JID and password options.
    parser.add_argument("-j", "--jid", dest="jid",
                        help="JID to use")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--password", dest="password",
                        help="password to use")
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--room", dest="room",
                        help="MUC room to join")
    parser.add_argument("-n", "--nick", dest="nick",
                        help="MUC nickname")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Setup logging.
    logging.basicConfig(level=args.loglevel,
                        format='%(levelname)-8s %(message)s')

    if args.jid is None:
        args.jid = "user@domain.lan"
    if args.password is None:
        args.password = "secretpassword"
    if args.room is None:
        args.room = "room@domain.lan"
    if args.nick is None:
        args.nick = "Nickname"

xmpp = MUCBot(args.jid, args.password, args.room, args.nick)
xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0030')  # Service Discovery
xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0045')  # Multi-User Chat
xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0199')  # XMPP Ping
xmpp.connect(('secretserver', secretport))
xmpp.process()
```

Comment: Can you include debug output?

Comment: @MattJ, I found the solution on my own. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
First of all I renamed the function `start(self, event)` to `session_start(self, event)`. Make sure to change the event handler as well to

`self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.session_start)`

Also make sure to use the correct roomid. It´s not only `room@domain.com`, you need the long number behind the text too. So go to the room configuration in Cisco Jabber and click on **Copy roomlink**. Just delete the `im:` in front.

And finally make sure you add your bot manually to the room and set it as moderator.